# Однонаправленный список

Tags: c, односвязный-список, указатели

Вообщем по заданию, мне надо перед указателем поместить элемент, то-есть, если мы имеем список 1 2 *3 4 5, где * указатель на текущий элемент, то после того как я вставил для примера 666, у меня должен получится воот такой уже список
1 2 *666 3 4 5 
Ниже приведен когд, когда указатель указывает на первый элемент, тоесть я переприсваиваю самый первый элмент, на котрый у меня всегда остается указатель

```
temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->value= n;
temp->next=lst;
lst=temp;
pr=lst;
printf("0.Введен %d елемент \n",n);
n++;
```

Ниже приведен когд, который работает, когда я сместил один раз указатель вправо, тоесть не изменяю "голову" списка

```
temp = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
temp->value = n;
temp->next=pr;
pr = temp;
printf("1.Введен %d елемент \n",n);
n++;
break;
```

Где pr - это указатель коорый я двигаю с помощью

```
pr=pr->next;
printf("Указатель смещен в право!\n");
```

и код с помощью которого я все вывожу

```
for(sp=lst;sp!=NULL;sp=sp->next){
printf("%d ", sp->value);
```

Проблема в том, что когда указатель указывает на голову, то все вставляется нормально, но как только я сдвинул указатель вправо, то он вроде бы добавляет, но уже не выводит. не подскажите, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вы можете объяснить, а зачем вы все это делаете? Зачем этот цикл с указателями, Чего вы хотите тем самым добиться?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow
Просто такое задание)
Структура данных типа «линейный однонаправленный список» При этом определяются
понятия «указатель списка» и «элемент списка за указателем». Операции,
выполняемые над списком:
● проверить, список пуст/не пуст;
● установить указатель в начало списка;
● добавить элемент за указателем;
● удалить элемент за указателем;
● просмотреть элемент за указателем;
● переместить указатель вправо;
● обменять значения конца списка и элемента за указателем

Comment: "Элемент списка за указателем - это какая-то безграмотность.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow
Ну почему, если представить список как 
*[]->*[]->*[]
Где * - указатель, а []  - тот самый элемент, то вполне логично, но просто у нас однонаправленный список, и получается "добавить элемент за указателем", то мы получается должны просто замеить этот элемент нановый,а старый элемент протолкнуть вперед, но так как у нас однонаправленный список, то это я не могу понять как делать, потому что получается, что мы должны сделать шаг назад...